# Magento 2.3 Product Images are not showing on HomePage?

Tags: magento2, php

Product images are not showing on home page.

> I am using porto theme in magento 2. Product images are not showing
>   but when i open detailed page then it will show product images.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Run the followin commands

1. php bin/magento cache:flush
2. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy